# Android Intents and Lists

Tags: java, android, list, android-intent

I plan on reading several files when my app/game is created and using the information from them for the entirety of the app. I also have to write to the file at one point.

I have two files. One is a 2-column text file that I'll turn into a dictionary for fast searching. The other is a text file that has 11 columns. I'll make a dictionary out of two of the columns, and the other data I need kept as is so I can write to the columns to count the amount of times something happens in different circumstances for datamining.

Currently, I've turned the second file into a list of a list of strings, or List>. I can't figure out how to pass that around in intents. ".putStringArrayListExtra" only works for a list of strings.

Am I going about this the wrong way entirely? This is my first real Android app.

Comment: Does this answer help? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087198/passing-a-list-to-another-activity-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087198/passing-a-list-to-another-activity-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to store a data structure into an `Intent`, it has to be either serializable or parcelable. If your data structure is neither of them, you might create a class that would `implement Serializable` and manage it. A good example might be found [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaSerialization/article.html).

Once done, you then might use `Intent.putSerializable(...)` to store your data structure. See this:

- [Using putSerializable in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132853/using-putserializable-in-android)

Additionally to this, if you could convert your structure into a `JSON` structure, you'd already have it done since it would be treated as a `String`. If not, the above solution should be easy to do.